# My a tags arent working in my dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

So I made a dropdown menu from a youtube video, I understood everything but, while I was making my website I got a problem where my a tags in li's weren't even working, only the first li showed that it had an a tag and that a tag didn't even work.
The dropdown menu is working but not the a tags, and I dont understand how isn't it working.
If anyone can help I'd appreciate it

```css
.dropdown {
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10%;
    background:#FAFAFA;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
.salons, .services {
    position: relative;
}

.services ul, 
.salons ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(10px);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.services a, .salons a, .about a, .contact a, .portfolio a, .somethingElse a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown button, .portfolio, .about, .contact {
    background:none;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.salons li, .services li {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.salons li a:hover, .services li a:hover {
    color: #dbd9d9;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.services button:hover {
    color: #dbd9d9;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.services button:focus + ul{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.salons button:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.salons button a:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.dropdown button {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="services">
<button>Сервисы</button>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">женская стрижка</a></li>
        <li><a href="facebook.com">услуги сушки феном</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">мужская стрижка</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">цвет волос</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">уход за волосами</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    
    
     <div class="salons">
<button>салоны</button>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">иосебидэе 53</a></li>
</ul>
     </div>
     <div class="about">
        <button><a href="">около</a></button>
      </div>
        <div class="portfolio">
            <button><a href="#">портфолио</a></button>
        </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <button><a href="#">кантакть</a></button>
            </div>
            <div class="somethingElse">
                <button><a href="#">еше</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try inverting the `<a>` and `<li>` tags. Instead of `<li><a>something</a></li>` try `<a><li>something</li></a>`.

Comment: As a general rule, `<a>` tags tend to work better as a parent then as a child.

Comment: I just tried that, but the same problem occured, pressing the first a tag didnt go anywhere and the other Li's arent showing up as a tags

Comment: `<a>` tags cannot contain `li`...it's in invalid HTML. @PedroLima

Comment: Also `button`s cannot contain `<a>` and vice versa.

Comment: the other thing i  tried is i deleted the container below my header, and the other a tags are showing up but as i said, they are not working, they are clickable but not functional

Comment: You have an overlapping issue. Your `ul`s are stacking on top of each other since you are using `opacity` to hide them. That's wrong. I think you should do the drop-down in a better way.

Comment: I fixed the problem, thank you everyone for the help, i was really sad about my project xD

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.dropdown {
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100%;
    background:#FAFAFA;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10;
    margin-left: 10px;
      overflow: visible;
    
}
.salons, .services {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.services ul, 
.salons ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: all;
    
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.services a, .salons a, .about a, .contact a, .portfolio a, .somethingElse a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown button, .portfolio, .about, .contact {
    background:none;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.salons li, .services li {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.salons li a:hover, .services li a:hover {
    color: #dbd9d9;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.services button:hover {
    color: #dbd9d9;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.services button:focus + ul{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.salons button:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.salons button a:focus + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.dropdown button {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="services">
<button>Сервисы</button>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">женская стрижка</a></li>
        <li>
        <a href="https://facebook.com">услуги сушки феном</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">мужская стрижка</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">цвет волос</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">уход за волосами</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    
    
     <div class="salons">
<button>салоны</button>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">иосебидэе 53</a></li>
</ul>
     </div>
     <div class="about">
        <button><a href="">около</a></button>
      </div>
        <div class="portfolio">
            <button><a href="#">портфолио</a></button>
        </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <button><a href="#">кантакть</a></button>
            </div>
            <div class="somethingElse">
                <button><a href="#">еше</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: yes, thank you so much, I can finally continue doing my project, i appreciate ur help